# How to better way to send optional params in react JS with AXIOS Api call

Tags: reactjs, parameters, axios

I am trying to make API in React JS with AXIOS. I need to send different types of params depends on params availability. Currently, I am calling like the below snippet and it is working as expected. The code becomes more lengthy when I have more optional values. How I can simplify or optimise the below api call

```
const axiosHandler = () => {
   
        let request;
        if (productID && type) {
            request = common.fetchDetails(
                { productID: productID, type: type },
                {
                    assignedTo: popUpID.current.toString(),
                    selectedItems: checkedItems,
                },
            );
        } else if (productID) {
            request = common.fetchDetails(
                { productID: productID },
                {
                    assignedTo: popUpID.current.toString(),
                    selectedItems: checkedItems,
                },
            );
        } else if (type) {
            request = common.fetchDetails(
                { type: type },
                {
                    assignedTo: popUpID.current.toString(),
                    selectedItems: checkedItems,
                },
            );
        } else {
            request = common.fetchDetailsWithoutParams({
                assignedTo: popUpID.current.toString(),
                selectedItems: checkedItems,
            });
        }
        request
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('res', res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('err', err);
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const axiosHandler = () => {

    let request;
    /**
    var productID='';var type=''; //modify this to test as per your neds
    var param ={
    ...(productID && {productID: productID}),
    ...(type && {type: type})
    }
    console.log(param)
    */

    if (productID && type) {

      //Use conditional spread operator
      const arg1 = {
        ...(productID && {
          productID: productID
        }),
        ...(type && {
          type: type
        })
      }
      const arg2 = {
        assignedTo: popUpID.current.toString(),
        selectedItems: checkedItems,
      }

      if (arg1) { //if both productID and type are empty arg1 will be undefined.
        request = common.fetchDetails(arg1, arg2);
      } else {
        request = common.fetchDetails(arg2);
      }

      request
        .then((res) => {
          console.log('res', res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('err', err);
        });
    };
```

Explanation:
You can use conditional spread operator to achieve this.

Rad more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

you can use spread operator for create object
for example for create object of your parameter :

```
  { ...(productID && false),  ...(type && false) }
```

in this approach for exmaple if productID is true return `{productID:productID}` and if type is true return `{type:type}` finally if both true return `{productID:productID , type:type}` and if any of parameter not defined or null :
spread before false not any return in object :
for exmaple return `{...false,...false} = {}`

Comment: this condition won't work either productID or type available right.. if both available then only it works right